# How to pass (start <= date1 and end >= date1) || (start <= date2 and end >= date2) condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms

Hi every one i want to pass condition like this:
**(start <= date1 and end >= date1) || (start <= date2 and end >= date2)** in laravel.
how to pass with this query?

```
$events = DB::table('christophheich_calendar_entries')->whereNull('deleted_at');
```

Any one can helpe ?
thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` statement like the following:

```
$events = DB::table('christophheich_calendar_entries')
    ->where(function($q) use($date1, $date2) {
        $q->where(function($q2) use($date1) {
            $q2->where('start', '<=', $date1)->where('end', '>=', $date1);
        })->orWhere(function($q2) use($date2) {
            $q2->where('start', '<=', $date2)->where('end', '>=', $date2);
        });
    })
    ->whereNull('deleted_at');
```

This is how to create a `where` clause with a inner query that handles the `or` part of the where. Make sure `$date1` and `$date2` are initialised before the query.